# Actions are stateless but are controllers stateless?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I think some of my understanding of MVC is fatally flawed.  I've always assumed that the action methods in a controller are stateless AND the controller itself is stateless.

So, is a new instance of the controller created every time any action is called?

Comment: Yes, controller is an object... IIS is an on-demand server. After action execution controller object will be disposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new instance of the controller is created for every *request* coming in. Consider this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return MoreIndex();
    }

    public ActionResult MoreIndex()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

A request coming in for `/Home/Index` will enter two actions, but only one controller is created. A request coming in for `/Home/MoreIndex` will enter one action and one controller is created. Now nothing prevents you from manually creating a controller and keeping it alive and re-using it. But it will never be in the context of an actual request coming from HTTP.

Comment: This page contains additional information you might find useful: http://blog.christopheargento.net/2012/06/11/detailed-life-cycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request/

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely reasonable to have state in the controller. I usually reference my database connection from a common controller base class. For that reason MVC creates a fresh controller for each request and properly disposes of it at the end.